# Set of positive real numbers with finite non zero limit point can be arranged in sequence $(a_n)$ with $(a_n^{1/n})_n$ convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

> Prove that a countably infinite set of positive real number with finite non zero limit point can be arranged in a sequence $(a_n)$ s.t $(a_n^{1/n})_n$ is convergent.

*I am not getting the proof*:

Let $(x_n)$ denote the real number and let $a$ be a finite non zero limit point. Choose $A$ s.t $1/A < a< A$ and let $a_1$ denote the $x_n$ of smallest subscript that lies in the interval $(1/A,A)$. Now I think that I have to go by induction that chosen $a_1,...,a_{k-1}$, I have to choose $a_n$ but I am not able to get the result.

Comment: What is $(x)_n$ ?

Comment: @Orace It's the given sequence.

Comment: Even if you make it work, your approach doesn't arrange all the $x_n$ in the sequence, just some chosen ones.

Comment: This is hard to believe.  Suppose $x_n=1, n\text{ odd}.$  Then $1$ is a limit point, whatever the even-numbered elements are.  Then it seems like, if the statement is true, it's true for any sequence whatsoever.  (I haven't proved this, I'm just saying it seems likely.)  What if the sequence is $1,2^2,1, 3^{3^3},1, 4^{4^{4^4}}, \cdots?$

Comment: I think if the limit points are finite , then you can calculate the $limsup$ and $liminf$ of the sequence $a_n ^{\frac{1}{n}}$ to conclude your result.Show they are equal.

Comment: The details may be tricky but I think this is true and the idea is simple.  You are going to arrange things so the limit of $a_n^{1/n}$ is 1.  For any $x > 0$, $x^{1/N}$ is close to 1 if $N$ is very large.  You have to arrange things so that $x_k$ appears very late in the sequence $a_n$ if either $x_k$ is very large or very small.  You have the freedom to do this because you have infinitely many terms of the original sequence in the interval $(1/A, A)$.

Comment: @saulspatz. I also thought it might be false but I have posted a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S=(x_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ be a positive real sequence  with $x$ being a positive limit point of $S.$ Let $f:\Bbb N\to \Bbb N$  be strictly increasing such that $x=\lim_{n\to \infty}x_{f(n)}$  and such that $\Bbb N \setminus f(\Bbb N)$ is infinite. This is possible because $S$ has a sub-sequence  $(x_{n_j})_{j\in \Bbb N}$ converging to $x$, and we may let $f(\Bbb N)=\{n_{(2j)}:j\in \Bbb N\}.$

Let $g:\Bbb N\to \Bbb N \setminus f(\Bbb N)$ be the (unique) order-isomorphism.   Take a strictly increasing $h:\Bbb N \to \Bbb N$  such that $h(n+1)\geq h(n)+2$ and where $h(n)$ is large enough that $|(x_{g(n)})^{1/h(n)}-1|\le1/n.$

Let $i:f(\Bbb N)\to \Bbb N\setminus h(\Bbb N)$ be the (unique) order-isomophism. Finally if $m=i(f(n))$ let $y_m=x_{f(n)}$ and if $m=h(n)$ let $y_m=x_{g(n)}.$

Comment: At first I thought it was false and tried to make a counter-example. The idea is that before we let $y_m=x_{g(n)},$ we include so many terms of the sequence $(x_{f(j)})_j$ as terms of the form $y_k$  with $k<m,$ that $m$ is so large that  $(x_{g(n)})^{1/m}$ is close to $1.$

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks for notifying me of the solution.  When I apply the logic to the sequence I suggested, the idea gets very plain.

Comment: Hi, can you please explain why the countable set $\{e^{n^2}: n\in \mathbb N\}\cup \{1+1/n: n\in \mathbb N\}$ is not a counterexample to the statement in OP?

Comment: @Koro . Let $x_{2n}=e^{n^2}$ and $x_{2n-1}=1+1/n.$ Let $f(n)=2n-1.$ Then $g(n)=2n.$ Let $h(n)=n^3.$ In the sequence $(y_m)_m$, if $m=h(n)=n^3$ then $y_m=x_{g(n)}=x_{2n}=e^{n^2}$ so $(y_m)^{1/m}=e^{1/n}. $ The members of $\{1+1/n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ are the terms $y_m$ for non-cubes $m$.  That is, $(y_m)_m=(e^1,1+1/1,...,1+1/6, e^4,1+1/7,...,1+1/24,e^9,...).$